# How to change Button name without changing the fontawesome icon with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have some jQuery code to change the button text when it is clicked. Originally (before clicking) the button is like this:

```
<button type="button"style="margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="image-remove-btn-4">
  <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> 
  Remove Photo
</button>
```

This is my jQuery to change button name to `Photo deleting...`

```
$("#image-remove-btn-4").text("Photo deleting...");
```

The button text is changed successfully but the problem is that the FontAwesome icon is removed once the button is clicked. Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like:

```
$("#image-remove-btn-4").html("<i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Photo deleting...");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the text for the `<i>` tag.

For example:

```
$(".fa-trash").text("Photo deleting...");
```